# For $\sum \|x_n\| \|x'_n\| < \infty$ and $\sum x'_n(x)x_n = 0$ for all $x \in X$ why is $\sum x'(x_n)x_n' = 0$ for all $x' \in X'$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am struggling to understand a proof about the approximation property on Banach spaces. The proof itself is pretty clear so I'll try to cut it down to the problem.

> (Lindenstrauss, Joram: Classical Banach spaces ; 1 . Sequence spaces Theorem 1.e.7)

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $X'$ its dual space. If $(x_n) \subset X$ and $(x'_n) \subset X'$ are such that $\sum \|x_n\|\|x_n'\| < \infty$ and $\sum x_n'(x)x_n = 0$ for every $x \in X$. Then also $\sum x'(x_n)x_n' = 0$ for every $x' \in X'$.

I dont quite see how this is clear.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: Suppose there is $x'$ such that $\lambda = \sum x'(x_n)x_n' \neq 0$. Then there is $y$ with $\lambda(y) \neq 0$. Try to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every   $x'$ in $X'$, and $x$ in $X$,
$$
\left(\sum x'(x_n)x_n'\right)(x) = 
\sum x'(x_n)x_n'(x) =
x'\left(\sum x_n'(x)x_n\right) =0,
$$
so the functional $\sum x'(x_n)x_n'$ vanishes everywhere.